# Probability to get the sum of $n$ random number equal to $s$

Tags: probability, summation

what is the probability to get a sum $s$ after $n$ independent random number generation events. We have the probability $P(X=x)$, i.e. the probability that the random number $X$ gets the value $x$. Let's assume that $x \in [0,x_{max}]$. Formally:

$$\sum_{t=1}^{n}X(t) = s~, \quad \text{with}~~ s > x_{max} ~~ \text{in general.}$$

The problem can be viewed as 'n' unfair dice rolls $x \in [0,5]$ with sum $s$.

Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure (but interested) if this can be answered without more information. At the very least, there would be a few conditions:

If $s$ is negative, the probability is zero. 

If $n \times x_{\max} < s$, the probability is zero. 

What is the exact probability distribution over $[0\ldots x_{\max}]$? Can we assume there is positive probability to reach $s$, if we are at any $s-\epsilon$?

Comment: This is the number of ways we can put $n$ indistinguishable balls into $s$ distinguishable boxes. Which is $\binom {n+s-1} {n}.$

Comment: @Dbchatto67does that assume the draws are from a discrete source?

Comment: I think if $x_{\operatorname{max}} \geq s$ then the required probability is $$\sum\limits_{x_1+x_2+\cdots + x_n =s} \prod\limits_{i=1}^{n} \Bbb P(X=x_i).$$ Where there are $\binom {n+s-1} {n}$ summands in the above summation.

Comment: In general $s > x_{max}$.